# Difference between Ember.Namespace & Ember.Object

Tags: ember.js

Consider this,

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create();
MyApp.someName = Ember.Namespace.create({
//my properties
});
```

I can do the same this using `Ember.Object` either...

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create();
MyApp.someName = Ember.Object.create({
//my properties
});
```

So, when should I use `Namespace` ? Where is the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look the [Namespace documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/namespace.js#L11):

> A Namespace is an object usually used to contain other objects or methods
>     such as an application or framework.  Create a namespace anytime you want
>     to define one of these new containers.

And the difference with an object is the `destroy` method, which remove the namespace from the namespaces list, as [you can see here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/namespace.js#L38):

```
destroy: function() {
  var namespaces = Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES;
  window[this.toString()] = undefined;
  namespaces.splice(indexOf.call(namespaces, this), 1);
  this._super();
}
```

Comment: Basically it is for a good practice I think, as we can see it extends Ember.Object so nothing much difference ..anyways Thanks for the clarification